# How to input ` in StackExchange

Tags: support, code-formatting

The ` is used to close the code-inline,But how can I input following code?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you need to post code with embedded back-ticks you can use double back-ticks to open and close.  To include code with double back-ticks you can use triple back-ticks to open and close, etc.

Examples: `` a`b`c `` and ``` 1.23``4 ```, entered with ``` ``a`b`c`` ``` and ```` ```1.23``4``` ```` respectively.

When entering code with leading or trailing back-ticks add a space between the opening and closing sets and the code body.

You can also use the four-space intent code block:

```
a`b`c
1.23``4
```

Comment: ...and if you need to convince yourself that it works, just look at [the source](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/1696/edit).

Comment: Thanks very much.^_^